# Removing ASCII "frame" around text

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I sometimes save nice fortune outputs to my Evernote. The data looks like this:

> ```
> / Abou Ben Adhem (may his tribe increase!)                    \
> | Awoke one night from a deep dream of peace,                 |
> | And saw, within the moonlight in his room,                  |
> | Making it rich, and like a lily in bloom,                   |
> | An angel writing in a book of gold.                         |
> | Exceeding peace had made Ben Adhem bold,                    |
> | And to the presence in the room he said,                    |
> | "What writest thou?"  The vision raised its head,           |
> | And with a look made of all sweet accord,                   |
> | Answered, "The names of those who love the Lord."           |
> | "And is mine one?" said Abou. "Nay not so,"                 |
> | Replied the angel.  Abou spoke more low,                    |
> | But cheerly still; and said, "I pray thee then,             |
> | Write me as one that loves his fellow-men."                 |
> | The angel wrote, and vanished.  The next night              |
> | It came again with a great wakening light,                  |
> | And showed the names whom love of God had blessed,          |
> | And lo!  Ben Adhem's name led all the rest.                 |
> \                 -- James Henry Leigh Hunt, "Abou Ben Adhem"
> ```

I am using the following regex:

```sh
$ cat abcd | sed -r 's/^[/|\\]\s?([-A-Za-z ()!,?".;'"'"']*)[/|\\]?/\1/'
```

> ```
> Abou Ben Adhem (may his tribe increase!)                    
> Awoke one night from a deep dream of peace,  
> ...
> ```

How do I improve it?

Comment: Do you just want to remove `|`, `/` and \ from the beginning and end of every line? I am asking this because I am not sure why your regex is so complicated.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Yes. I simply can't figure out a simpler way.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex looks complicated. What's more, it doesn't work:

```
$ cat fortune | sed -r 's/^[/|\\]\s?([-A-Za-z ()!,?".;'$a']*)[/|\\]?/\1/'
Abou Ben Adhem (may his tribe increase!)
Awoke one night from a deep dream of peace,
And saw, within the moonlight in his room,
Making it rich, and like a lily in bloom,
An angel writing in a book of gold.
Exceeding peace had made Ben Adhem bold,
And to the presence in the room he said,
"What writest thou?"  The vision raised its head,
And with a look made of all sweet accord,
Answered, "The names of those who love the Lord."
"And is mine one?" said Abou. "Nay not so,"
Replied the angel.  Abou spoke more low,
But cheerly still; and said, "I pray thee then,
Write me as one that loves his fellow-men."
The angel wrote, and vanished.  The next night
It came again with a great wakening light,
And showed the names whom love of God had blessed,
And lo!  Ben Adhem's name led all the rest.                 |
                -- James Henry Leigh Hunt, "Abou Ben Adhem"
```

See this stray `|` in the second line from the bottom? Honestly, I didn't analyze why your regex doesn't work because, as I said, it looks horribly complicated. But, first of all, `cat` is not necessary here because most of `sed` implementations - `GNU`, `busybox`, `BSD` can operate on a file directly and some of them even take `i` parameter which makes `sed` modify a file in place. That being said, here's how I would do it:

```
$ sed -r 's,^(/|\||\\) ,,g' fortune | sed -r 's,(\\|\|)$,,g'
```

I tested it with `GNU sed 4.2.1` and with `busybox` version of `sed` on `OpenWRT`. The only thing that I don't like about it is usage of `-r`. There may be some basic `sed` implementations that don't implement extended regular expressions but they should be very rare.

**EDIT:**
No chaining with `perl`:

```
$ perl -pe 's,^(/|\||\\) (.+?)(\\|\|)?$,\2,' fortune
```

Comment: I will agree it's complicated, but it **definately** works. I edited the question. And yours only removes the ending tag. That is trivial. I need a better way to capture the middle string.

Comment: No, I use `|` to chain two `sed` commands. The first one removes redundant characters at the beginning: `s,^(/|\||\\) ,,g`. What version of `sed` do you use? I use `fortune` as the file name.

Comment: Thanks! I incorporated your suggestion and indeed using two sed is much simpler. However, I am wondering if it's possible to do it with just one? And sure `sed -r <file>` is better, but I find `cat <file> | sed` easier to read.

Comment: @prakharsingh95: in the old days, there used be something called [useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) on `Usenet`. To answer your question - I wouldn't go with `sed` if I wanted to avoid chaining because `sed` does not support non-greedy matches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed. I would use `Perl`. I will update my answer in a second.

Comment: Thanks. I generally use Regex in Java or online, and I never thought `sed` wouldn't support non-greedy. Accepting this answer.